# How do I fix newly added hard drives in Disk Management?

Tags: partitioning, installation

I've added some new hard drives to my ASUS-DELUXE motherboard running Win 64.

- Disk 0, (T:) has a 1.82GB NTFS Healthy Primary Partition and a blue bar over that but under a black bar it says 1861.20 GB Unallocated. How do I fix that?
- Disk 2 (H:) says 1863.01 GB NTFS healthy (Primary Partition), is this H: disk set up properly and ready to use for storage of video?
- Disk 3 (S:)  Is the main disk I use for video storage.  It says New Volume (S:) and I am using it for video storage and editing, the entire disk says 1863.01 GB NTFS Healthy (Primary Partition) and it is working fine.
- Disk 6 (K:) first part says 1.82GB NTFS Healthy (Primary Partition) under a blue bar and the remainder of the disk says 1861.20GB Unallocated.

Do I need to do anything else before I start using these newly installed hard drives?

I mainly want to use them to store video projects for long term storage to free up more space on my S: drive.

Comment: A screenshot of what you are seeing would be extremely helpful here.

Comment: Just format the drives with GPT and not MBR.

Comment: I agree, a screenshot would be helpful to prevent wrong advice being given due to a mix-up. In general though you can create new partitions for the unallocated areas, or merge those areas with adjacent partitions to create bigger partitions.

Answer (score 1):

With the unallocated spaces on disk 0 and disk 6 you have 2 options;

a) you can create one or more new partitions in that space. Right click on the unallocated space and click on 'New Simple Volume' (see Picture)

> **Note:**My pictures look different than you will see them on your screen. I have to work with a high contrast theme because of my bad
>   eyes.

[image]

Then you get the partition creation Wizard where you click on 'Next' and will come to the next picture where you have to allocate the amount of MBs (Mega Bytes) that you want this partition to be.

[image]

Then you keep clicking 'Next' until you get to the 'Finish'. If you have unallocated space left, you can repeat this procedure to create further partition(s).

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

b) Your other option for the unallocated space it to add all or part of that space to the existing partitions 'T' on disk 0 and 'K' on disk 6. For that you right click on those partitions and click on 'Extend Volume'.

[image]

You will see another Wizard similar to the one above but the space allocation picture is a bit different. Again you have to choose the whole amount of MBs or only a portion if you want to reserve some for an additional partition(s).

[image]

When you are done with the allocation, click 'Next' and then 'Finish'.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use GPT on hard drives less than 2tb, all you need to do is format the 2 drives showing unallocated space as suggested by whs in their answer.

Disk 0 create a simple volume (MBR) as suggested by whs

Disk 2 is ready to use and should show up in windows explorer as Drive H

Disk 3 is ready to use and should show up in windows explorer as Drive S

Disk 6 create a simple volume (MBR) as suggested by whs

As always suggested have backups of any data you cannot afford to lose Before using disk management to make these changes.